# 'Functionally' produce a list with only a few elements

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

This is purely an exercice of though, but given this code:

```
var someCondition = (....);
var res = [];
if (someCondition) {
   res.push("A");
}
res.push("B");
if (someCondition) {
   res.push("C")
}
return res;
```

What would be a more "functional" way to express the list ?

I could come would be something like (in JS, with underscorejs reduce, with is basically a fold)

```
_.reduce(["A", "B", "C"], function (memo, value, index) {
     if (index === 0 || index === 2) {
        if (someCondition) {
           memo.push(value);
        }
     } else {
        memo.push(value);
     }
}, []);
```

Or with a filter:

```
_.filter(["A", "B", "C"], function (value, index) {
    if (index === 0 || index === 2) {
       return someCondition;
    } else {
       return true;
    }
});
```

Now, this sounds a bit ugly... Am I missing an obvious solution here?

Comment: I'd go with something like `zip ["A","B","C"] [cond, True, cond] \`mayMaybe\` (\(a, b) -> if b then Just a else Nothing)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about `filter`?

```
_.filter(['A', 'B', 'C'], function(value, index){
    if (index === 1 || index === 2) {
        return someCondition;
    }
    return true;
});
```

Comment: I updated my question just a second after I posted it ; I though about filter, but again, the condition seems strange, expressed this way..

Comment: `return (index === 1 || index === 2) ? someCondition : true;`

Comment: @DavidThomas, `!(index === 1 || index === 2) || someCondition`?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would not treat this as a candidate for filter function, because array indices are important.
For me the first functional approach is something like this:

```
[].concat(someCondition ? ['A'] : [],
          ['B'],
          someCondition ? ['C'] : []);
```

The advantage here is a dissociation from the particular indices and ability to insert other items more easily.

Answer (score 0):

The way to express what you want to do is with [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

Say you have a condition:

```
function isEven(n) {
  return n % 2 === 0;
}
```

and a list of numbers from `0` to `20`, inclusive:

```
const A = [...Array(21).keys()];
```

If you want the even numbers from that list, you could do:

```
A.filter((n) => isEven(n));
```

Similarly, if you wanted the odd ones:

```
A.filter((n) => isOdd(n));
```

The important thing, and maybe the most important idea of [Functional Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming), is that the array `A` was **not modified** by that process: the function simply took and returned data, and the result of the function call will be the same everytime the data sent in is the same. No state management and no side effects.